# Toggle between focus and blur in a manner similar to the hover() method does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a website in Bootstrap 4, that has a search bar.

I want to toggle between `focus` and `blur` attaching both events to the `#group-search input` element. I was looking for a clear and concise way to make this work, like the `hover()` method works:

```js
$('#group-search input').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('div').removeClass('dark');
}, function() {
  $(this).closest('div').addClass('dark');
});
```

```css
#group-search {
  padding: 5px;
}

#group-search input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#group-search.dark input,
#group-search.dark button {
  color: #444;
}

#group-search.dark button {
  border: none;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="group-search" class="input-group dark <?php if(form_error('search')) echo 'has-error';?>">
  <input class="form-control form-control-dark" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search posts..." aria-label="Search">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The way I use `focus` and `blur` events, to my surprise, does not work.

```js
$('#group-search input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).closest('div').removeClass('dark');
}, 'blur', function() {
  $(this).closest('div').addClass('dark');
});
```

```css
#group-search {
  padding: 5px;
}

#group-search input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#group-search.dark input,
#group-search.dark button {
  color: #444;
}

#group-search.dark button {
  border: none;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="group-search" class="input-group dark <?php if(form_error('search')) echo 'has-error';?>">
  <input class="form-control form-control-dark" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search posts..." aria-label="Search">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind both events and just toggle the class.

```js
$('#group-search input').on('focus blur', function() {
  $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('dark');
});
```

```css
#group-search {
  padding: 5px;
}

#group-search input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#group-search.dark input,
#group-search.dark button {
  color: #444;
}

#group-search.dark button {
  border: none;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="group-search" class="input-group dark">
  <input class="form-control form-control-dark" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search posts..." aria-label="Search">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, here is how you should use it

```js
$('#group-search input').on({
    focus: function() {
        $(this).closest('div').removeClass('dark');
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(this).closest('div').addClass('dark');
    }
});
```

```css
#group-search {
  padding: 5px;
}

#group-search input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#group-search.dark input,
#group-search.dark button {
  color: #444;
}

#group-search.dark button {
  border: none;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="group-search" class="input-group dark <?php if(form_error('search')) echo 'has-error';?>">
  <input class="form-control form-control-dark" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search posts..." aria-label="Search">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

See here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/#many-events-and-handlers